# Visualize binary-sensor data via matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, time-series, sensors

So I have a tuple containing two lists from my data base. This is a binary sensor that checks if a window is open. I want a visualization with matplotlib like this:

[image]

So I guess I nee something like a stacked horizontal bar graph? I'm at a loss here, so any help is appreciated. It is fine to assume that the value always starts at 0.0 (window closed) and changes to 1.0 when the window is first opened. I attach the tuple from my database here:

`([datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 30, 6, 59, 12, 935971, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 30, 7, 4, 47, 367527, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 30, 16, 51, 54, 169183, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 30, 16, 59, 5, 211397, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)], [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0])`

Comment: maybe a heatmap to represent the binary values across the timestamps ?

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?